# How to manage empty result set from SQL query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is what I have:

**Problem 1**: Some companies don't have "R&D Expenses" at all. In which case `select` statement would return nothing (that's the **H** case). When this happens the entire SQL returns nothing. So, if data is there - it works fine. If any data isn't there the whole thing comes back empty.

**Problem 2**: If you can please help make this SQL simpler I would really appreciate it. I am not a SQL guy and know that this is probably very ugly.

Instead, I want to get a column named "R&D Expenses" full of 0.[image]

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _vars;
CREATE TABLE _vars(companyTicker);
INSERT INTO _vars(companyTicker) VALUES ('INTC');

select A.date, 

     Case when (a.rawvalue is null or a.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else a.rawvalue/1000000 end Revenue,
     Case when (b.rawvalue is null or b.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else b.rawvalue/1000000 end GrossProfit,
     Case when (c.rawvalue is null or c.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else c.rawvalue/1000000 end NetIncome,
     Case when (d.rawvalue is null or d.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else d.rawvalue/1000000 end RevCO,
     Case when (e.rawvalue is null or e.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else e.rawvalue/1000000 end _SGA,
     Case when (f.rawvalue is null or f.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else f.rawvalue/1000000 end _DA,
     Case when (g.rawvalue is null or g.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else g.rawvalue/1000000 end _NI,
     Case when (h.rawvalue is null or h.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else h.rawvalue/1000000 end _RND,

     Case when (bs_a.rawvalue is null or bs_a.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else bs_a.rawvalue/1000000 end Cash,
     Case when (bs_b.rawvalue is null or bs_b.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else bs_b.rawvalue/1000000 end CA,
     Case when (bs_c.rawvalue is null or bs_c.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else bs_c.rawvalue/1000000 end CL,
     Case when (bs_d.rawvalue is null or bs_d.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else bs_d.rawvalue/1000000 end TA,
     Case when (bs_e.rawvalue is null or bs_e.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else bs_e.rawvalue/1000000 end TL,
     Case when (bs_f.rawvalue is null or bs_f.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else bs_f.rawvalue/1000000 end RetainedEarnings

    from incomeStatements as A

 inner JOIN incomeStatements as B on A.date = B.date
 inner JOIN incomeStatements as C On A.date = C.date
 inner JOIN incomeStatements as D On A.date = D.date
 inner JOIN incomeStatements as E On A.date = E.date
 inner JOIN incomeStatements as F On A.date = F.date
 inner JOIN incomeStatements as G On A.date = G.date
 inner JOIN incomeStatements as H On A.date = H.date
 inner join balanceSheets as BS_A on A.date = BS_A.date
 inner join balanceSheets as BS_B on A.date = BS_B.date
 inner join balanceSheets as BS_C on A.date = BS_C.date
 inner join balanceSheets as BS_D on A.date = BS_D.date
 inner join balanceSheets as BS_E on A.date = BS_E.date
 inner join balanceSheets as BS_F on A.date = BS_F.date

 where A.companyticker = (select companyticker from _vars) and A.lineitemname = 'Revenues' and A.timescale = 'annual'
    and B.companyticker = (SELECT companyticker from _vars)   and B.lineitemname = 'Gross Profit' and B.timescale = 'annual'
    and C.companyticker =  (SELECT companyticker from _vars)  and C.lineitemname = 'Net Income to Company' and C.timescale = 'annual'
    and D.companyticker = (SELECT companyticker from _vars)   and D.lineitemname = 'Earnings From Continuing Operations' and D.timescale = 'annual'
    and E.companyticker = (SELECT companyticker from _vars)   and E.lineitemname = 'Selling General & Admin Expenses' and E.timescale = 'annual'
    and F.companyticker = (SELECT companyticker from _vars)   and F.lineitemname = 'Depreciation & Amortization' and F.timescale = 'annual'
    and G.companyticker = (SELECT companyticker from _vars)   and G.lineitemname = 'Net Interest Expenses' and G.timescale = 'annual'
    and H.companyticker = (SELECT companyticker from _vars)   and H.lineitemname = 'R&D Expenses' and H.timescale = 'annual'
    and BS_A.companyticker = (SELECT companyticker from _vars) and BS_A.lineitemname = 'Cash And Equivalents' and BS_A.timescale='annual'
    and BS_B.companyticker = (SELECT companyticker from _vars) and BS_B.lineitemname = 'Total Current Assets' and BS_B.timescale='annual'
    and BS_C.companyticker = (SELECT companyticker from _vars) and BS_C.lineitemname = 'Total Current Liabilities' and BS_C.timescale='annual'
    and BS_D.companyticker = (SELECT companyticker from _vars) and BS_D.lineitemname = 'Total Assets' and BS_D.timescale='annual'
    and BS_E.companyticker = (SELECT companyticker from _vars) and BS_E.lineitemname = 'Total Liabilities' and BS_E.timescale='annual'
    and BS_F.companyticker = (SELECT companyticker from _vars) and BS_F.lineitemname = 'Retained Earnings' and BS_F.timescale='annual'
order by A.Date Asc;

DROP TABLE _vars
```

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` in place of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @nick This didnt change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace your `INNER JOIN`s with `LEFT JOIN`s and put all the `WHERE` conditions into the `JOIN` conditions so that rows are still returned when a value (e.g. `'R&D Expenses'`) is missing. You can also simplify your query somewhat by `JOIN`ing the `_vars` table. Unfortunately that's about all you can do to simplify because of your EAV table structure you do need to `JOIN` to each table once to get each different value. Here's a shortened version of what your query should look like:

```
SELECT a.date,
       Case when (a.rawvalue is null or a.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else a.rawvalue end Revenue,
       Case when (h.rawvalue is null or h.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else h.rawvalue end _RND,
       Case when (bs_a.rawvalue is null or bs_a.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else bs_a.rawvalue end Cash,
       Case when (bs_d.rawvalue is null or bs_d.rawvalue ='')  then 0 else bs_d.rawvalue end TA
FROM _vars
LEFT JOIN incomeStatements a ON a.companyticker = _vars.companyticker AND a.lineitemname = 'Revenues' AND a.timescale = 'annual'
LEFT JOIN incomeStatements h ON h.date = a.date AND h.companyticker = _vars.companyticker AND h.lineitemname = 'R&D Expenses' and h.timescale = 'annual'
LEFT JOIN balanceSheets bs_a ON bs_a.date = a.date AND bs_a.companyticker = _vars.companyticker AND bs_a.lineitemname = 'Cash And Equivalents' AND bs_a.timescale = 'annual'
LEFT JOIN balanceSheets bs_d ON bs_d.date = a.date AND bs_d.companyticker = _vars.companyticker AND bs_d.lineitemname = 'Total Assets' AND bs_d.timescale = 'annual'
```

And a [demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f9443f78205c1e8218c88bc0fad827b3) of that query working with a very limited dataset.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. It took me some time to understand what you did here, but it works. Appreciate you taking the time to offer an example!

Comment: @JamesRaitsev no worries - I realised that it was too complicated to try and explain via comments and an example is, like a picture, worth 1000 words...